# How to setup certificates for tls connection using python ssl

Tags: python, ssl, networking, network-programming, certificate

I have been struggling with this for a few days. I have a tls server running and some c code on another machine that connects to it. When i try to connect I get the error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV2_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv2 alert unknown ca
```

I guess this is because the client certificate is self signed and thus the server doesn't recognise the ca. A way around this i suppose is to somehow have the certificate for the client stored on the server so that when it is connected to it can verify the certificate since it has it stored as trusted already. In terms of how to do this I am not sure. I have seen the method "context.load_verify_locations('path/to/cabundle.pem')" but I am not sure which certificate/how to generate a certificate for this method param.
I have been going in circles with generating certificates and trying lots of different ways. So now I just want to generate it from scratch but I haven't really been able to find any help online that works.

Here is my server code:

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM
import ssl
import os

certs_path = "certs/"
SERVER_CERT = os.path.join(certs_path, "dev_server.crt")
SERVER_KEY = os.path.join(certs_path, "dev_server.key")

ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8443
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.load_cert_chain(SERVER_CERT, SERVER_KEY)

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', port))
sock.listen(5)

print(f"Listening for TCP connections on port: {port}")

while True:
    connection, sender = sock.accept()
    sec_sock = context.wrap_socket(connection, server_side=True)
    request = sec_sock.read()
    decoded = request.decode("utf-8")
    print(f"Received {decoded} from {sender[0]}:{sender[1]}")
```

My question is, if i were to generate certificates from scratch to use with this server and client how would I do so?

Comment: you can set up your own CA with https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa

Comment: Could you be more detailed? I have tried following the readme for easy rsa here: https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/master/README.quickstart.md
but I find it quite confusing.

i.e how to create the req file on the client and what to use for each "EntityName"

Comment: entityname can be whatever you want, for testing you can just use "client" and "server". here is a advanced documentation https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/master/doc/EasyRSA-Readme.md and here https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/master/doc/Intro-To-PKI.md